# Install Wordpress Theme Components on Demand

Tags: php, wordpress

So I'm working on an idea; theoretical at this point, but I'm hoping that I can get some help. Is there a way that I can install theme files into a Wordpress installation from a theme admin page?

Example: I have 4 CSS files stored on a server that correspond to 4 different styles of theme layout. When the base them is installed, there are no CSS files installed. On a backend admin page, the user could select 1 of the 4 CSS files (presumably after paying, right?), and the theme itself would download the file to the wp-content folder and hook it into the theme.

Thoughts? Is this something I can do? Is there documentation on this out there? Would it just be hooking into the PHP filesystem functions?

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of plugins have premium (paid) addons working this way.

For example, https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-google-maps/ has a base plugin with a premium addon that installs separately from a different server.

Theme and plugin installation operations basically unzip files and drop them in the right place under the control of WordPress.

The software doing that is in the WordPress source code file wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php . You can probably just invoke it. If not you can certainly adapt it.

Comment: I don't want to go out and buy the addons to test, but it looks like it shoots out to a separate website for the purchase. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Wordpress, it's 100% customizable from a PHP programmer's point of view. Customized options are usually set in the Wordpress admin area. You can create custom admin pages and options that can do anything you can dream of. Here's where to start:

```
http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus
```